# Can not disable Server Feature WebDAV Redirect for SharePoint 2019 Server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, windows-server-2016

I have SharePoint 2019 Farm in Production and enabled Open with Explorer view by Enable Server feature WebDAV Redirect, now i want to disable this server feature and what are recommmended steps to disable this server feature without impact to Production web application document libraries data and its SharePoint Permissions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The recommended steps to disable WebDAV Redirect feature for SharePoint 2019 Server are as follows:

1.Stop the web client service in the windows services.

2.Server Manager Dashboard -> Manage -> Remove roles and features.

[image]

3.Remove WebDAV Redirector feature.

In theory, disabling this feature does not affect the production web application document library data and its SharePoint permissions.

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.